# Video cutting with minimal re-encoding or no re-encoding

Tags: video, video-editing, video-encoding

I want to cut a video file (i.e. delete parts of it), and do it with the minimum amount of re-encoding possible.

I found this piece of software called [Machete](http://www.machetesoft.com/), which otherwise works fine, but it makes me set the cut points to [key frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-frame). I want to be able to set the cutpoints to any kind of frame I want (which AFAIK means there has to be some re-encoding).

I've tried Avidemux, but it creates broken files if I don't set the cut points to key frames.

Comment: It's non-trivial to write something that will do what you want, but a workaround is to cut the largest chunk possible by key frames and then combine them with the other pieces edited in standard software like virtual dub using a mux tool.

Comment: There's no "minimum amount of re-encoding"—there either is, or there isn't. If you cut at intra-frames, it'll work without encoding, of course, and vice-versa.